# Dynamically generate a list of names based on an empty cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel 2016 spreadsheet where I am tracking whether or not people have completed a weekly form. This form has a different topic each week. On Sheet 1 (2018) is my master listing of topics and team members with an "X" in the cell indicating whether or not they have turned the form in. On Sheet 2 (Check-In Sheet), I have a drop down box where I can select a topic. My ultimate idea was to select the topic and retrieve a list of people who have not completed the topic selected. Below is a sample screenshot of Sheet 1. So, from this screen shot, if I select "Safety Resolution", a list on the second page would contain the names (Robin, Aron)(Beane, Isaac)(Beene, Roger)(Benitz, Jose) and so on.

[image: Sreenshot from Sheet 1]

Answer (score 0):

You could copy all contents from col C onwards, paste into a new sheet, and select "transpose" from the Paste-Smarttag. Then you get Forms as Cols and Names as Rows, you can filter (per Col) for all rows without an "X".

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you want to go formula-wise instead of Copy and Paste, you could add a new sheet, put "E" into A2, "F" into A3 and autocomplete to "T" (or however many cols the first sheet has). 
In B2, you could write `=INDIRECT(CONCAT(A2;1))` and c&p that formula down (so the 2nd col has all the names). You can intro another col per form and pull the "X" es similarly via `=INDIRECT(CONCAT(A2, 2))` (for first form), `..., 3))` for the 2nd one, etc. Again, you can filter for empty cols.

Yet another alternative (quicker, just not that obvious): on a 2nd sheet, select as many rows as you have names plus one and as many cols as you have forms plus one, type `TRANSPOSE(` and select from col C rightwards / downwards and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (or <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a Mac probably). The formula then auto-magically transposes (and updates upon changes in the source sheet). You find more info on this [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027).